# How to instantiate classes outside of Webpack bundle?

Tags: typescript, webpack, ecmascript-6

I have a library written in TypeScript and Webpack. I'd like to construct new objects outside of the webpack bundle like this:

var myNewObject = WebpackLibraryTargetName.ExportedClass;

This works fine if I write the appropriate JS in a file and include it in webpack's compilation process, but I need to be able to expose the functions so that it can be used outside, too.

What other information would be useful to include here?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `output.library` and `output.libraryTarget` in order to expose like a global namespace in your webpack connfiguration.
https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-library